# How can I vectorize approximate matrix multiplication using rows time columns?

Tags: python, numpy

I have two matrices `A` and `B`, and I want to compute their **AMM** *(Approximate Matrix Product)* using a subset of rows and columns.
Assume that I have two probability distributions `pr` and `pc`, respectively, for the rows of `A` and the columns of `B`.
`A` and `B` are each of size 900 x 900

I choose a row from `A` with row distribution `pr` with probability *p* and a column from `B` with distribution `pc` with probability *(1-p)*.

This means I am choosing *kp* rows from `A` and *k(1-p)* columns from `B`, where `k < D`

A sample code is given below,

```
import numpy as np
D = 1000
p = 1/2
k = 500
# Assume uniform distribution for this case
pr = np.full(D, 1/D)
pc = pr
indexR = np.random.choice(1000, int(k*p)+1, p=pr)
indexC = np.random.choice(1000, int(k*(1-p))+1, p=pc)

A = np.random.uniform(0,1,(D,D))
B = np.random.uniform(0,10,(D,D))

# True multiplication
C = A @ B

C_hat = np.zeros((D,D))
# Approx. Multiplication
for r in indexR:
    for c in indexC:
        C_hat[r,c] = np.inner(A[r,:],B[:,c])
```

How can I remove these for loops?

Comment: What should `kp` be?

Comment: Does `A[indexR,:] @ B[:,indexC]` give the same answer as `C_hat`?

Comment: Please run your code snippet and correct errors, like `kp` instead of `k*p` and `C_hat[i,j]` with `i` and `j` undefined

Answer (score 1):

`indexR` and `indexC` can contain **duplicates**. Thus it is better to remove them first. **Sorting indices** can also help to improve performance since modern processor really do not like *random memory accesses* (since they cannot *prefetch* data from RAM as the addresses cannot be *predicted*). Then `np.inner(A[r,:],B[:,c])` is nothing more than a dot product and you can rewrite the dot product of many operation as a simple **vector-matrix product** or **matrix multiplication**.

```py
unique_indexR = np.unique(indexR)
unique_indexC = np.unique(indexC)

c_indices = np.tile(unique_indexC, len(unique_indexR))
r_indices = np.repeat(unique_indexR, len(unique_indexC))

C_hat = np.zeros((D,D))
C_hat[r_indices, c_indices] = (A[unique_indexR,:] @ B[:,unique_indexC]).reshape(-1)
```

Here are performance results (on my 6-core machine):

```
Initial time:         261.46 ms
Vectorized version:     3.67 ms
```

Thus, the vectorized code is **71 times faster**.

Comment: Would you explain hwo tile and repeat works?

Comment: Also, why are you using reshape with `B`?

Comment: The idea is to generate all the indices `(r, c)` that your loop generates. In your loop, the values of `indexC` are repeated `len(indexR)` times (eg. 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 ...). I use `np.repeat` to repeate the value of an array similar to this loop. Similarly, `np.tile` repeat each items N times (eg. 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 ...). As for the `reshape`, the idea is that `C_hat[r_indices, c_indices]` can only be assigned to a flatten array. Thus, I flatten the matrix produced by the matrix multiplication (not just `B`) using `reshape(-1)`.

Comment: I tried your solution and it reduced the run time from 46 minutes to 12 minutes. for 900*900 matrices

Comment: I seems a bit slow. Your example with a bigger matrix (1000x1000) should run in no more than few seconds even on slow machines. It probably worth profiling the code to see what is slow. If this is the matrix multiplication, then please check you are using OpenBLAS or more generally a parallel BLAS (note that there are plenty of post on SO about this point).